# The geojson point data markers are not clustering in leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, geojson, markerclusterer

I am using leaflet-markercluster plugin for cluster my point data. I already loaded my geojson data named as 'street' into map. this data having around 40 points with their respective attributes. I want to cluster these points in leaflet map. But even markers are not showing in my map. Please help me to find out the error. My code is here:

```
var OpenStreetMap_Mapnik = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var street = {...my_geojson_data...}

var s_light_style = {
    radius: 8,
    fillColor: "#ff7800",
    color: "#000",
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    fillOpacity: 0.8
};


var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
L.geoJSON(street, {
    onEachFeature : function(feature, layer){
        var popupContent =  '<h4 class = "text-primary">Street Light</h4>' +
                            '<div class="container"><table class="table table-striped">' +
                            '<thead><tr><th>Properties</th><th>Value</th></tr></thead>' +
                            '<tbody><tr><td> Name </td><td>'+ feature.properties.Name +'</td></tr>' +
                            '<tr><td>Elevation </td><td>' + feature.properties.ele +'</td></tr>' +
                            '<tr><td> Power (watt) </td><td>' + feature.properties.Power_Watt + '</td></tr>' +
                            '<tr><td> Pole Height </td><td>' + feature.properties.pole_hgt + '</td></tr>' +
                            '<tr><td> Time </td><td>' + feature.properties.time + '</td></tr>';
        layer.bindPopup(popupContent)
    },
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return markers.addLayer(L.marker(latlng))  
    }
}).map.addTo(markers);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace the code by

```
L.geoJSON(street, {
    onEachFeature : function(feature, layer){
        var popupContent =  '<h4 class = "text-primary">Street Light</h4>' +
                            '<div class="container"><table class="table table-striped">' +
                            '<thead><tr><th>Properties</th><th>Value</th></tr></thead>' +
                            '<tbody><tr><td> Name </td><td>'+ feature.properties.Name +'</td></tr>' +
                            '<tr><td>Elevation </td><td>' + feature.properties.ele +'</td></tr>' +
                            '<tr><td> Power (watt) </td><td>' + feature.properties.Power_Watt + '</td></tr>' +
                            '<tr><td> Pole Height </td><td>' + feature.properties.pole_hgt + '</td></tr>' +
                            '<tr><td> Time </td><td>' + feature.properties.time + '</td></tr>';
        layer.bindPopup(popupContent)
    },
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return markers.addLayer(L.circleMarker(latlng, s_light_style))
    }
})
map.addLayer(markers);
```

In above code i specify the map.addTo(markers). But actually I have to replace "addTo" keyword with "addLayer". I have to add the layer. In this way I solved the geojson markerCluster problem.